# I wish to merge records within a single table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a single table with some duplicate records all bar one column.

e.g.

Field-A  Field-B  Field-C

abc      abc       Fred

abc      abc       Harry

def      cba       Bert

def      wxy       David

def      wxy       Peter

def      wxy       Larry

I wish to crunch this table down in T-SQL (SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure) so that where columns Field-A and Field-B are the same across two or more rows the resulting table will have one row with Field-C as a merger of the others.

So, for the above example the resulting table will be..

Field-A  Field-B  Field-C

abc      abc       Fred, Harry

def      cba       Bert

def      wxy       David, Peter, Larry

Is there any way that this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Field-A, 
Field-B, 
(SELECT Field-C + ',' from yourtable y WHERE y.Field-A=x.Field-A and y.Field-B=x.Field-B FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM yourtable x
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a genius. I've written a short test Query to check out your answer and it works. Much appreciated. Now to apply it to the final product... Hooray!